# If statement to set limits of what elements in 2d array are accessible. c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, 2d, uwp-xaml

I am trying to set the boundaries of a game I'm writing, which looks like this:

[image]

When a circle is clicked and it has a neighbouring circle and the neighbouring circle has an empty space this space is colored red to indicate that the move can be made.

The areas with blue crosses are considered "out of bounds", and I don't want to show those spaces as move possibilities when the user clicks on a circle.

---

**Example**

In the image below, the circle with the blue`X` is the one that has been clicked. The red squares with the blue x's are out of bounds and should not be highlighted as possible moves.

[image]

I have been testing out different combinations of the below code but still have had no success as of yet. `curCol` and `curRow` are the values of the clicked circle's x and y coordinates, which map to the 2d array, as both are 0 indexed.

```
//name for getting the position of the peices on the board.
if (curCol > 1 && curRow > 1 && curRow < 5 &&curCol > 5)
{
    if (twoSquaresDown < 7)
    {
        if (grid[twoSquaresDown, curCol].Equals(brdr) && 
            !grid[oneSquareDown, curCol].Equals(brdr))
        { 
            // grid = new UIElement[9, 9];
            possible1 = new Border();
            possible1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            possible1.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, twoSquaresDown);
            possible1.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, curCol);
            possible1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            possible1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

            //@todo set height and width of squares not hard coded.
            possible1.Height = 100;
            possible1.Width = 100;
            possible1.Name = "possible1";

            grdGame.Children.Add(possible1);

            possible1.Tapped += Brdr_Tapped;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your current code not working?

Comment: Hi Rufus I want the red squares to be highlighted only if they are within the game grid not the brown part at each corner. The out of bounds elements are  {0,0},{0,1},{1,0},{1,1} in the 2d array for the top left portion of the grid. im testing this part first as the other three corners will have the same logic if working.

Comment: What is `brdr`? Can you define another type like this (called something like `outOfBounds`) and assign it to the out-of-bounds array items? Then you could add the condition `&& !grid[twoSquaresDown, curCol].Equals(outOfBounds)` (or perhaps this would already be true if you can avoid ever setting it to `brdr`).

Comment: brdr is a Border UI element that i have in the array. There is either a Border (brdr) or Ellipse (myEl) held within the array.

Comment: I'll try your idea of setting the out of bounds items to another variable i recon that will work.

Comment: Thank you Rufus for your time i really appreciate it.

Comment: You can also have your game board and non-game board elements extend from the same type which has an 'IsHighlighted' dependency property.  Then use a style template for each which has the border around the control that's shown when IsHighlighted is true on the game board element, but does nothing on the non-game board brown area.  Then you just have to worry about bounds check with the entire board.